# css fluid layout image issues

Tags: html, css, resolution, fluid-layout

okay im making a layout that has two sides. the left is 30% and the right 70%. i have a widescreen monitor so all the images will display how i want them too with good room left. BUT on lower resolutions and the most common 1024x768, the image i made is too big for the left side and goes out of the borders onto the right side.. how would i make the image automatically resize to fit on smaller resolutions?

## CSS

```
#left {
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  padding:20px;
}

#right {
  float:right;
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  padding:40px 20px;
}
#left img {
  ??
}
```

Comment: Some example html would help. Its hard to see what you are doing exactly from our end ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `max-width` and a percentage value on the image. This way the image will never exceed that percentage.

For example:

```
img {
    max-width:90%;
}
```

Comment: that sounds right. im guessing it resizes the image to make sure it fills 90% of the div width?

Comment: If you haven't applied any other size attributes on the image it display at full size unless its full width is larger than 90% of the div that it's contained in, in which case its width will only be 90% of the div it's contained in.

Comment: If you want it _always_ at 90% of the div then just do width:90%.

Comment: okay thank you Danny Cooper. and which would you prefer for a logo?

Comment: It depends, do you have a link to your site?

Comment: well its larzconwell.com but the part im working on isnt up at all right now, its going to look way different lol

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your image, you could just add `overflow: hidden` on the `#left` div.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is add the image to the background of the `#left div`.

The image will not resize but it will also not flow over the borders.

You could make the background resize using CSS3, although there is not full browser support.

`background-size:100% 100%;` will make sure the image sizes to the entire `div`.  However there may be some distortion.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
#left img {
  width: 100%;
}
```